# How to fix an "expected primary-expression" error

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project in our programming class which requires me to make an inventory system. There is an error in the code in line 243 that gives weird errors when I compile it.

Line 243 beneath in the code is

while(inventory>>rec.prodtype>>rec.menutype>>rec.prodnum

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
COORD CursorPosition;

void gotoXY(int x, int y);
void add();
void view();
void menu();
void types();
void input();
void stock();
void find_name();
void find_number();
void find_type();
void find_mtype();
void all();
void output();

struct inventory{
    string prodtype,menutype;
    string prodnum,prodname;
    int quantity;
    float prodprice;
}rec;

int main()
{
    int x=1,y=1; //for gotoXY
    char l; //choice to determine add/view
    system("cls");
    cout<<"\n\nÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ";
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t  INVENTORY SYSTEM\n";
    cout<<"ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ";
    cout<<"\n\t\t   ---- [1]  Add new product           ----"
        <<"\n\t\t   ---- [2]  Add stocks to existing products   ----"
        <<"\n\t\t   ---- [3]  View Products         ----"
        <<"\n\t\t   ---- [4]  Exit Program          ----"
        <<"\n\n\t\t\t\t  Enter choice : ";
    back:
    l=getch();
    if(l=='1')
    add();
    else if(l=='2')
    stock();
    else if(l=='3')
    view();
    else if(l=='4')
    return 0;
    else
    goto back;
}

void stock_intro()
{
    cout<<"\n\nÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ";
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t   ADDING OF STOCKS\n";
    cout<<"ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ\n\n";
}

void stock()
{
    string num; //for inputting prodnum...
    int x; //for adding stocks
    string prodtype,menutype;
    string prodnum,prodname;
    int quantity;
    float prodprice;
    ifstream inventory("inventory.txt");
    system("cls");
    stock_intro();
    cout<<"\t\t\t     Enter Product Number to add stock:\n\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t     ";
    cin>>num;
    while(inventory>>prodtype>>menutype
          >>prodnum>>prodname>>quantity
          >>prodprice){
            system("cls");
            cout<<"How many stocks would you like to add?: ";
            cin>>x;
            rec.quantity=rec.quantity+x;

          }
}

void types()
{
    ofstream inventory("inventory.txt", ios::app);
    char c;
    cout<<"\n\nÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ";
    cout<<"\t\t\t\tFOOD AND BEVERAGES\n";
    cout<<"ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t [A] SNACKS\n\t\t\t\t [B] CANDIES\n\t\t\t\t [C] BISCUITS\n\t\t\t\t [D] CHOCOLATES\n\t\t\t\t [E] CANNED GOODS\n\t\t\t\t [F] CONDIMENTS\n\t\t\t\t [G] INSTANT NOODLES\n\t\t\t\t [H] BEVERAGE / DRINKS\n";
    cout<<"\n\t\t\t\t Enter Choice: ";
    back:
    c=getch();
    c=toupper(c);
    if(c=='A')
    rec.menutype="SNACKS";
    else if(c=='B')
    rec.menutype="CANDIES";
    else if(c=='C')
    rec.menutype="BISCUITS";
    else if(c=='D')
    rec.menutype="CHOCOLATES";
    else if(c=='E')
    rec.menutype="CANNED GOODS";
    else if(c=='F')
    rec.menutype="CONDIMENTS";
    else if(c=='G')
    rec.menutype="INSTANT NOODLES";
    else if(c=='H')
    rec.menutype="BEVERAGE / DRINKS";
    else
    goto back;
    inventory<<rec.menutype;
}

void input()
{
    system("cls");
    cout<<"\n\nÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ";
    cout<<"\t\t\t\tADDING OF PRODUCTS\n";
    cout<<"ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ\n\n";
    ofstream inventory("inventory.txt", ios::app);
    cout<<"\t\t\tEnter Product number: ";
    cin>>rec.prodnum;
    cout<<"\t\t\tEnter Product name: ";
    cin>>rec.prodname;
    cout<<"\t\t\tEnter Product price: ";
    cin>>rec.prodprice;
    cout<<"\t\t\tEnter Quantity: ";
    cin>>rec.quantity;
    inventory<<endl
             <<rec.prodnum<<endl
             <<rec.prodname<<endl
             <<rec.prodprice<<endl
             <<rec.quantity<<endl<<endl;
}

void add()
{
    char c,d; //for choosing food or hygene
    char e; //for choosing if add another of not
    back2:
    system("cls");
    cout<<"\n\nÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ";
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t     ADD PRODUCTS\n";
    cout<<"ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ";
    ofstream inventory ("inventory.txt", ios::app);
    cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\t[A] FOOD and BEVERAGES\n\t\t\t\t[B] HYGIENE";
    cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\tEnter Choice: ";
    back1:
    c=getch();
    d=toupper(c);
    if(d=='A')
    rec.prodtype="Food & Beverages";
    else if(d=='B')
    rec.prodtype="Hygiene";
    else
    goto back1;
    system("cls");
    inventory<<rec.prodtype<<endl;
    types();
    input();
    cout<<"\n\t\t\tEnter another product? [Y / N]: ";
    back3:
    e=getch();
    e=toupper(e);
    if(e=='Y')
    goto back2;
    else if(e=='N')
    main();
    else
    goto back3;
}

void output()
{
    cout<<"Product Type: "
        <<rec.prodtype<<endl;
    cout<<"Menu Type : "
        <<rec.menutype<<endl;
    cout<<" Product Number: "
        <<rec.prodnum<<endl;
    cout<<" Product Name: "
        <<rec.prodname<<endl;
    cout<<" Product Price: "
        <<rec.prodprice<<endl;
    cout<<" Stocks Available: "
        <<rec.quantity<<endl;
}

void view_intro()
{
    system("cls");
    cout<<"\n\nÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ";
    cout<<"\t\t\t\tVIEWING OF INVENTORY\n";
    cout<<"ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ\n";
}

void view()
{
    char ch;
    system("cls");
    view_intro();
    cout<<"\n\t\t        ---- [1]  Find by Product Name   ----"
        <<"\n\t\t        ---- [2]  Find by Product Number  ----"
        <<"\n\t\t        ---- [3]  Find by Product Type   ----"
        <<"\n\t\t        ---- [4]  Find by Menu Type      ----"
        <<"\n\t\t        ---- [5]  Display all Records     ----"
        <<"\n\n\t\t\t\t  Enter choice : ";
    back:
    ch=getch();
    ch=getch();
    switch(ch)
    {
        case '1': find_name();break;
        case '2': find_number();break;
        case '3': find_type();break;
        case '4': find_mtype();break;
        case '5': all();break;
        default: goto back;
    }
}

void find_name()
{
    string name;
    int v=0;
    system("cls");
    view_intro();
    ifstream student("record.txt");
    cout<<"\n Enter Product Name [incorrect capitalization is invalid]: ";
    cin>>name;
    system("cls");
    view_intro();
    while(inventory>>rec.prodtype>>rec.menutype>>rec.prodnum
           >>rec.prodname>>rec.prodprice>>rec.quantity)
    {
        back:
    while(name==rec.prodname)
    {
        output();
        break;
        }
        v++;
        if(v<1)
        {   
        goto back;  
        }
}
        system("pause");
        main();
}

void gotoXY(int x, int y) 
{ 
CursorPosition.X = x;
CursorPosition.Y = y;
SetConsoleCursorPosition(console,CursorPosition);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org).  Also what line is line 243?

Comment: Also calling `main()` in your program is illegal. C++14 3.6.1(3) `The function main shall not be used within a program.`

Comment: I'm so sorry, I am rushing and I put too many details. And this is line 243

 while(inventory>>rec.prodtype>>rec.menutype>>rec.prodnum

Answer (score 1):

In `find_name()` function:

```
while(inventory>>rec.prodtype>>rec.menutype>>rec.prodnum
           >>rec.prodname>>rec.prodprice>>rec.quantity)
```

You dont declare what `inventory` is in this function. Did you mean to open a file in a variable called `inventory` like you did in the other functions?

The reason the compiler is giving weird errors is you declared a type called `inventory` and so not seeing a local variable called inventory it assumes you're using the type which makes no sense in the context of the above line and the compiler gets confused and gives a fairly obscure error.

Comment: They do have `ifstream student("record.txt");` so it could be a copy and paste error.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yup that does indeed look like the issue

Comment: Is there a format in copy-pasting a code to be retrieved in the compiler?